# Converting 32-bit android Applications to 64-bit Applications

Tags: android, apk, 64-bit

when i try to upload my up to google play i receive this erreur

Error
This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 6.

Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app.

[image: here the image]

Answer (score 0):

yes, the issue is you have not updated your library in Gradle some of your libraries still build in native 32-bit that's why u are getting this issue to fix this see all folders have the same no of file. And update ur Gradle libraries

Comment: Please, I need help because I have already made many attempts and it did not work out
I downloaded some folders and placed them inside a libs folder, but the application did not work
Please, what steps do I have to take in order for this to work? I've been trying for ten days
I would be grateful if you could help me

Comment: check folders-  ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64' check these folders have same so files or not if not then there is any library thats is in 32 bit if not working share some code base of gradle

Comment: all those so file same in all folders

Comment: please im tired to find any solution how ca i do that